# Checkbox CSS cannot change background color for the checkbox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to change my checkbox to this color #FA9E57. I am using bootstrap v 4.6.

This is my checkbox code:

```css
input[type=checkbox]{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #FA9E57;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked{
    background-color: #FA9E57;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;500;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="register.css">
    <title><%=judul %></title>
    
    <body>
    <div class="form-group my-4">
       <div class="form-check">
         <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="privacy">
         <label class="form-check-label ml-3" for="privacy">
          Agree privacy
         </label>
       </div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: You are missing a closing `</head>` tag. Is that a transcription error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can't modify checkbox color.**

Instead, create pseudo elements with background custom background color, like this :

```css
.form-check {
  position: relative;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked+label::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  left: 0;
  top: 5px;
  background-color: #FA9E57;
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(150 150 150 / 30%);
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked+label::after {
  content: url('data:image/svg+xml; utf8, <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="14" height="14" fill="white" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M20.285 2l-11.285 11.567-5.286-5.011-3.714 3.716 9 8.728 15-15.285z"/></svg>');
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 3px;
  top: 3px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;500;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="register.css">

<div class="form-group my-4">
   <div class="form-check">
     <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="privacy">
     <label class="form-check-label ml-3" for="privacy">
      Agree privacy
     </label>
   </div>
</div>
```

*:before element is used to set background color, and :after element contain svg for checkmark.*

Answer (score 85):

You can use `accent-color` CSS property to change the background-color of both checkbox and radio buttons.

```
input[type=checkbox] {
  accent-color: red;
}
```

This will only show the color once the input is checked/selected.

Answer (score 4):

Please add some css code.

```
input[type=checkbox], input[type=checkbox]:checked {
  -moz-appearance:none;
  -webkit-appearance:none;
  -o-appearance:none;
}
```

In order for your code to work, you need the above code.

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

css and html for checkbox

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
.container input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

/* Create a custom checkbox */
.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #FA9E57;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
.container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #FA9E57;
}

/* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #FA9E57;
}

/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

/* Show the checkmark when checked */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}

/* Style the checkmark/indicator */
.container .checkmark:after {
  left: 9px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<label class="container">Agree privacy
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: What did you change from OP's code? Unexplained blocks of code are rarely useful.