# change border color of an input checbox (CSS)

Tags: html, css, input, checkbox

hi try to change my checkbox border with a specific color, but doesnt work

```css
input[type="checkbox" name="checkbox-140"] {
  background-color: cyan;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cf7b-row">
  <p><span class="cf7b-label-checkbox-140"></span>
  </p>
  <div class="cf7b-group-checkbox-140">
    <p><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap" data-name="checkbox-140"><span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox wpcf7-exclusive-checkbox"><span class="wpcf7-list-item first"><label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-140" value="Herr"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Herr</span></label>
      </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item last"><label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-140" value="Frau"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Frau</span></label>
      </span>
      </span>
      </span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

the css is a try for see if works but no, not work at all

Comment: you need to add `appearance: none`

Comment: is the answer help  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66383850/checkbox-css-cannot-change-background-color-for-the-checkbox